# Toggling the visiblity of a entry on button click - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I need some help sorting the visibility of entry on a button click. I have tried a few different things. and the following code is the best result that I have got so far.  But its not perfect either.

Requirement: When the page shows in the screen, it would have just a button visible, and when the user clicks on the button, it shows the entry, if they click on the button again, the entry should be set to invisible. If i click outside else where in the page, it should also hide the entry.

XAML.

```
 <controls:CustomButton 
           Text="Submit" 
           TextColor="White"  
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
           Command="{Binding TextSubmitCommand}"
           Icon="WhiteKeyboard"/>

           <controls:CustomEntry 
                    x:Name="ItemEntry"
                    TextColor="White"                                    
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    IsVisible="{Binding EntryVisible, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <controls:CustomEntry.Behaviors>
                        <behaviors:EventToCommand 
                            Command="{Binding LocationSearchCommand}"
                            EventName="Completed"/>
                    </controls:CustomEntry.Behaviors>
                   <controls:CustomEntry.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger TargetType="controls:CustomEntry"
                                     Binding="{Binding EntryVisible}"
                                     Value="true">
                           <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <triggers:EntryFocusTrigger/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </controls:CustomEntry.Triggers>
                </controls:CustomEntry>
```

View Model

```
    public bool EntryVisible { get; set; } = false;

    public Command TextSubmitCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                EntryVisible = !EntryVisible;
            });
        }
    }
```

Trigger

```
 public class EntryFocusTrigger : TriggerAction<CustomEntry>
 {
    protected override void Invoke(CustomEntry entry)
    {
        entry.Focus();
    }
 }
```

With the above code, it works perfectly fine toggling the visibility on button click. But if i click else where in the page, the keyboard hides, but the entry will still be there. So i tried adding an event trigger.

Added the following xaml to the custom entry in (XAML Page)

```
<EventTrigger Event="Unfocused">
    <triggers:EntryUnfocusTrigger />
</EventTrigger>
```

and the actual trigger is defined as:

```
public class EntryUnfocusTrigger : TriggerAction<CustomEntry>
{
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    protected override void Invoke(CustomEntry entry)
    {
        if(entry.IsFocused == false){
            entry.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But after adding the above code, the entry does not show at all after the first toggle. What would be a clean way to get this working. Look forward for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `Trigger` to hide when the Entry is not Focused:

```
<Trigger TargetType="controls:CustomEntry"
        Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="false" />
</Trigger>
```

With this one you don't need a custom Trigger class.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: It works better. I have also made IsVisible property binding mode to default. But there is still one odd case, where we tap on the screen else where, the keyboard disappears, but then i need to tap two times on the button to get the entry back on, since the visibility property is not binded back to view model

Comment: It shouldn't be the case since you are binding back to your ViewModel when you do this `IsVisible="{Binding EntryVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: @LibinJoseph i re-read your last comment. Do not use `Mode=Default` since you are changing the IsVisible from the View so you need to notify your ViewModel of the change. You need to keep it  `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: If I add Mode=TwoWay, I need to tap twice for the entry to disappear. When I click first time, it disappears the keyboard, second tap it works